# Existence of $G$ such that $\mathbb{E}[\exp(X/\alpha)] \leq G$

Tags: analysis, inequality, random-variables, exponential-function, expected-value

Let $M > 0$ and $\alpha >0$ and consider a random variable $X$ such that $\mathbb{E}[|X|] \leq M$. I'm looking for an upper bound for $\mathbb{E}[\exp(X/\alpha)]$. The only inequality I know that switch the expectation and the exponential is Jensen's inequality but it is not useful here. Any hints or directions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no upper bound in general. If $X\sim \textrm{Pareto}(1,2)$, then $E[|X|]=2$ but
$$E[e^{X/\alpha}]=2\int_1^\infty e^{x/\alpha}x^{-3}dx=\infty,\,\forall \alpha >0$$

Comment: Under which condition on $X$ do you think such a bound can exist.

Comment: @Jeremy there is established research with results such as [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_lemma). Look for bounds on moment generating functions.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Let $X_n$ be a probability distribution such that $\mathbb{P}[X_n=Mn]=\dfrac{1}{n}$ and $\mathbb{P}[X_n=0]=\dfrac{n-1}{n}$.

Now $\mathbb{E}[|X_n|]=M$

but $\mathbb{E}[\exp(X_n/\alpha)]=\dfrac{\exp(Mn/\alpha)}{n}+\dfrac{n-1}{n}$ which grows to infinity as $n$ tends to infinity.

Comment: Just a detail: shouldn't it be $E[e^{X_n/a}]=e^{Mn/a}/n+(n-1)/n$?

Comment: @Snoop ah yes thanks

Comment: @ChrisSanders: Under which condition on $X$ do you think such a bound can exist?